Vitest having issue with @popperjs/core as it is CommonJS Package
Module /..../node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/flip.js:1 seems to be an ES Module but shipped in a CommonJS package. You might want to create an issue to the package "@popperjs/core" asking them to ship the file in .mjs extension or add "type": "module" in their package.json
Getting the above error while running test cases using vitest.
vitest says there's one temporary workaround, but seems like even that isn't working:
// vitest.config.js
export default {
  test: {
    server: {
      deps: {
        inline: [
          "@popperjs/core"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

I tried adding the above workaround, but it didn't seem to work.
@popperjs/core is widely used in our project and this is blocking us from running test cases.
Is there anything in vitest similar to transformIgnorePattern in jest? maybe that can help here

How can I have funtionality similar to transformIgnorePatterns in vitest, this may help me resolving the above issue

I had a similar issue with a different package so not sure if my solution will work.
Try importing popper to your setupFiles file. import "@popperjs/core".
Other than that, using cjs is deprecated in Vite so you need to start using mjs which can be done by adding "type": "module" to your project's package.json.

Not working, outputting same error

@SanketMundada which version are you using?

"@popperjs/core": "2.4.0"
And for vite 5.2.10

@SanketMundada have you tried the latest version 2.11.8?

Still now working

Is there anything in vitest similar to transformIgnorePattern in jest, maybe that can help here
